# Selection highlights don't appear in Visual Studion 2013 Ulitmate

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have recently installed Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.
There is a feature in Visual Studio which highlights all the matching words in the opened document.

So if the file contains the word 'Void' many times then highlighting it in one place would also highlight it wherever it occurs.

Additionally small blue lines would be shown on the right scroll bar indicating where the word occurs in the current document.

This feature is either not working or enabled in my current installation.

Can someone please guide me?

Thanks in advance.
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this guide:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2013/07/18/visual-studio-2013-reference-highlighting.aspx

> C#:  Go to Tools | Options | Text Editor | C# | Advanced.  Uncheck the "Highlight references to symbol under cursor" option.

[image: Highlight references to symbol under cursor - C#]

Answer (score 0):

There should also be a similar option under general that would allow you to enable the highlighting. Frankly, I'm confused as to how a version installed without it enabled already; considering it is the most convenient thing about Visual Studio.

Comment: is this referring to the [answer by DeJaVo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29841710/3297440)? The "similar option" seems to suggest so. It can be helpful to [link to a referenced answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45597/how-can-i-link-to-a-specific-answer) if so since the answers move on the page based on votes.

Comment: Yes, that is in fact what it was intended for. I appreciate the guidance! I'm kind of new to everything on this.. haha @lilbill39